# Is .map() sufficient or should I use ListView (or FlatList) in React Native?

Tags: javascript, listview, react-native

I have an app that renders a list of `sentences`. Currently, I am rendering something like this:

```
{this.state.sentences.map((sentence, key) => {
    return (
        <Text key={key}>{sentence}</Text>
    );
}
```

Should this be rewritten with `ListView` or `FlatList`?

```
return (
    <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.sentences}
        renderRow={sentence => <Text>{sentence}</Text>}
    />
);
```

What advantages and disadvantages will ListView have compared to using JavaScript's `.map()`?

Answer (score 1):

Better start using FlatList or SectionList since ListView is now Deprecated.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html

Using .map is totally fine but I think you'll get tons of great features and the Native feeling easily with the FlatList or SectionList which you might not get easily when just using

There are few Caveats like you must use a FLUX/ REDUX or RELAY. Please Checkout the details here (Features/Caveats) 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html